# "center view to mouse" stopped working with "alt middle mouse"

Tags: objects

it just stopped working the shortcut to center view to mouse. in a new project from scratch it works as usual.
but the thing is im in the middle of a hard working file and it is a pain in the ass having to open a new file again and append everything from there.
i checked in the "keymap" and the short cut is there.
manually when i try "view -> align view -> center view to selected" it just disappeared from its usual place. i'm getting sabottaged by some hacker bulliyng me?
It maybe a joke to someonelse but not for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that destroying the 3d mini windows by joining the neighbour mini window over it , and after that changing the mini window to 3d view again it sorts out.